# Function for moving data without slowing code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code so that when I press `checkbox`, the code will find the first empty row and put data there, see:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    const INPUT_ROW_INDEX = 6;
    if (INPUT_ROW_INDEX === 6) {
        const range = e.range;
        const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); `enter code here`

        const rowIndex = range.getRow();
        const columnIndex = range.getColumn();
        const value = range.getValue();

        if (value === true) {
            const startColumnName = columnToLetter(columnIndex - 6);
            const endColumnName = columnToLetter(columnIndex - 1);
            const firstFreeColumnName = columnToLetter(columnIndex - 2);

            const firstFreeRowIndex = getFirstEmptyRowByCell(firstFreeColumnName, INPUT_ROW_INDEX + 1, spreadSheet);

            const copyRange = spreadSheet.getRange(startColumnName + rowIndex + ":" + endColumnName + rowIndex);
            const deleteRange = spreadSheet.getRange(startColumnName + rowIndex + ":" + firstFreeColumnName + rowIndex);

            copyRange.copyTo(spreadSheet.getRange(startColumnName + firstFreeRowIndex + ":" + endColumnName + firstFreeRowIndex), {
                contentsOnly: true
            });
            deleteRange.clear();
            range.setValue(false);
        }
    }
}

function columnToLetter(column){
    var temp, letter = '';
    while (column > 0) {
        temp = (column - 1) % 26;
        letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
        column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
    }
    return letter;
}


function getFirstEmptyRowByCell(firstFreeColumnName, startIndex, spreadSheet) {

    var range = spreadSheet.getRange(
        firstFreeColumnName + ':' + firstFreeColumnName);
    for (var i = startIndex; i <= range.getLastRow(); i++){
        if (!range.getCell(i, 1).getValue()) {

            break;

        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

My question is, if there exists some function or trick, so that when I press the  `checkbox` data will move right under the checkbox row, and the row under the `checkbox` will be always empty, and I can repeat it how many times I want.

Thank for any advice.

Jan

Comment: Unfortunately there is no trick or predefined functions for doing the same , u have to write your own logic for this

Comment: can we see your html ? what data you want to paste it to the first row ? first row in the entire page , or in a particular div , or in a table please provide more info

Comment: Unrelated, but I fixed the indentation in your JavaScript and it appears you've forgot a bracket `{` for the last for loop in `getFirstEmptyRowByCell`. I didn't want to fix it in case the typo was something that caused validity for your question.

Comment: Whole logic is that this script is used for writing working hours, now it is working when I press checkbox data will move to the first empty cell which is in the end of the table. I want to move data to the start of the table that I can see data at first sight and not scrolling to the end of the table.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV  its date data, only first row its moving like its working now, see the code. I want to move data (one row) under the row where is checkbox. Whole logic is that my data will move under chceckbox row and after that there will be always free row for faster code working, and final step will be that whole data in table will move down in one row. Hope this is understandable.

Comment: @JánKolodzej Would you please share your spreadsheet?